# 46.38 Cannot open file, path = 'pubspec.lock' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13) ------ Dockerfile:41

Tags: flutter, docker, permissions, dockerfile

I would like to dockerize my Flutter app so I put my Flutter application files in the directory `workspace/demo`.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Prerequisites
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl git unzip xz-utils zip libglu1-mesa openjdk-8-jdk wget

# Set up new user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash developer
USER developer
WORKDIR /home/developer

# Prepare Android directories and system variables
RUN mkdir -p Android/sdk
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT /home/developer/Android/sdk
RUN mkdir -p .android && touch .android/repositories.cfg

# Set up Android SDK
RUN wget -O sdk-tools.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip
RUN unzip sdk-tools.zip && rm sdk-tools.zip
RUN mv tools Android/sdk/tools
RUN cd Android/sdk/tools/bin && yes | ./sdkmanager --licenses
RUN cd Android/sdk/tools/bin && ./sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.2" "patcher;v4" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29" "sources;android-29"
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/developer/Android/sdk/platform-tools"

# Download Flutter SDK
RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/developer/flutter/bin"

# Run basic check to download Dark SDK
RUN flutter doctor

# Create a directory for your Flutter project
RUN mkdir -p /home/developer/my_flutter_app

# Copy your Flutter project files to the Docker image
COPY ./workspace/demo /home/developer/my_flutter_app

# Set the working directory to your Flutter project
WORKDIR /home/developer/my_flutter_app

# Run Flutter commands to build your app
RUN flutter pub get
RUN flutter build apk
```

I get this error:

```
46.38 Cannot open file, path = 'pubspec.lock' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

When building the docker image I tried to change permissions but did not achieve a successful result.

How to fix that please help.